# Do assets have to be below public_html to access them in redactor?

Tags: assets, url, filesystem

I love that Redactor lets you choose existing entries, categories, and assets!

I am trying to set up a 'Files' source whose File System Path would be something like

```
/home/hostingaccount/craft/files
```

where index.php is at

```
/home/hostingaccount/public_html/index.php
```

But what source URL can point to that file location? It doesn't like `http://mydomain.com/files`. Or am I all wrong, and the assets have to be in something like this:

```
/home/hostingaccount/public_html/files
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Asset source file system path needs to be under your `public_html` folder, so your 2nd example is correct: `/home/hostingaccount/public_html/files`.

Then your corresponding Asset source URL would be `http://mydomain.com/files`.

Correct that, then Asset related functionality (including Redactor's) should start working.